# iPhone log in to Google App Engine

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine

Is there any way to log into a Google account from inside an iPhone application if you know the username and password of the account.  I want to be able to do this without making the user type in the information each time the app has to login.  I need to do this so I can have a login system accessable from the iPhone SDK.  Actually any login system will do if it can run on the app engine.

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I just had to write my own login engine.

Comment: And this doesn't seem to be an answer. You can help the community by pasting the codes.

Answer (score 9):

You will probably want to take a look at this framework, [touchengine](http://code.google.com/p/touchengine/), which is used for communication between Cocoa Touch and Google App Engine. There is also an interesting article at IBM titled [Connecting Apple's iPhone to Google's cloud computing offerings](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web//library/wa-aj-iphone/), which highlights touchengine.

A quote of touchengine's future feature list:

- User Authentication
- Creating new data or modifying data on the server from iPhone using plists this is partially done. We can set most db.properties from strings.
- Modifying/Updating existing data on server from iPhone using plists
- Libraries Libraries Libraries -- starting with a user defaults sync solution
- Automated synchronization of model on iPhone and on GAE

Comment: This looks great, except for the fact that "User Authentication" is under the "Future Features" list - not there yet

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I misread. I will clarify the text in this post.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the keychain services available on the iPhone to securely store the user's credentials? Then just access those credentials whenever you need to log into the app engine.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190963/can-i-access-the-keychain-on-the-iphone) question on accessing the keychain on the iPhone for some links and additional abstraction layers to make your life easier.