# Login with google account

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, ios5

I want to use login with my gmail account in iPhone. I have a login screen where i have implemented login with Facebook and twitter but for google i dont have any idea. Can any one let me know from where i can start to implement the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow [this](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Signing_In_to_Google_Services) documentation for Google account authentication integration in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Check This [gtm-outh2](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/)
You can look at this [Example](http://code.google.com/p/touchengine/) and [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) or just look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1569324

I hope it helps you.