# iphone security data encryption

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, security, encryption

Hey.  I would like to save sensitive user data to my apps sandbox but I know that if the phone is then stolen someone can "rip" (if thats the correct term) data off the device quite easily.

So I need to use encryption. But I can't use standard private-public keys without either storing them in the code. (not good im assuming as if the bundle is cracked they could be discovered)

Or using a secure connection to a server to transmit keys, which will mean my app will have to have internet to encrypt... not the best option for me.

So Im thinking of having the user enter a password or pin that will be used to encrypt the data (is that called a Hash?) but how secure is that? if someone ripped the hard drive of the phone and got my hash out. would they be able to decrypt all/any of it?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190963/can-i-access-the-keychain-on-the-iphone) addresses keeping a password safe for your app.  Instead of a password, store a random key for encrypting a file, [like this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html).

Don't roll your own security code, your questions reveal you're nowhere near being able to do that and get it right... keep reading, but for now follow these examples.

Comment: Thanks, yes your correct iv only just started out on this, was planning on using those categories, So really I just need to know how secure it is.... If an attacker has all the time in the world to try to decrypt data can they succeed ? Cheers

Comment: If they literally do, then yes.  But in practice, the point of cryptography is to make it impractical without resources so huge that nobody will be able to muster those resources.  I should have given you a reference for generating the key as well, but I don't have one handy.