# iPhone: membership

Tags: iphone, membership-provider

in .Net we can use membership provider See [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx3h274z.aspx)

Whether there are any equivalent in iPhone or is it possible to access these provider through iPhone API

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190963/can-i-access-the-keychain-on-the-iphone)?