# Keychain to store and read username and password

Tags: iphone, keychain

Can anyone tell me please whats the easiest way to use Keychain to store and read username and password values?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does this have a negative rating? When you vote down something take the time to comment and mention what's wrong too. How are users expected to learn if noone says what's wrong? Lily: this Stack Overflow question might help you get going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190963/can-i-access-the-keychain-on-the-iphone

Comment: Concerns are accepted... I have given this question negative rating because it doesn't describe question at all....use keychain to store username and password.... ? whose password...? certificate P12 cer file... What where how... ? Nothing... but i don't know why you have up voted it... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go...

Courtesy of [ldandersen (Buzz Andersen)](http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security)