# Security in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keychain

My problem is :
1. I am developing an iPhone application i have proceded like this :
the user authentication, with a user name and a password ( after a verification with web services), my question is how it is stored the username and the password in my application. are there secured or did i proced to implement a secure mechanism ?

thanks for your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using [SFHFKeychainUtils](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security). It uses apple's Security Framework.
It's easy to use, to save a Username and Password:

```
[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:userNameString andPassword:passwordString forServiceName:@"YourServiceName" updateExisting:TRUE error:&error];
```

and to retrieve the encrypted password for a Username

```
[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:userNameString andServiceName:@"YourServiceName" error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Keychain : [Keychain iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190963/can-i-access-the-keychain-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score -2):

**Saving:**

```
NSUserDefaults *userNamePrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSUserDefaults *passwordPrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userNamePrefs setObject:@"username" forKey:@"username"];
[passwordPrefs setObject:@"password" forKey:@"password"];
```

**Retrieving**

```
NSUserDefaults *userNamePrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSUserDefaults *passwordPrefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *savedUsername = [prefs stringForKey:@"username"];
NSString *savedPassword = [prefs stringForKey:@"username"];
```

*what else UITextbox User enter just match the string like*

```
if ((usernameTextBox.Text isEqualToString(savedUsername)) && (passwordTextBox.Text isEqualToString(savedPassword)) ){
    // pass authentication
}
else{
  // show alert view fail authetication
}
```

Comment: You save the password as plain text in the user defaults?! I really really hope that I have and will never ever use an app from you

Comment: no i just recommend, its mean not that u forcefully use that. i just have a optional advice infact me to use SFHFKeychainUtils in my apps for security purpose... Its just easy thats why, sorry if u mind