# Best approach of Encryption of local database in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, ios, encryption

Is there any apple documentation which suggest the best way to encrypt the local database. I have done it using SQLCipher. Just wanted to know if there is any material out there by Apple addressing how this can be done.

Comment: this might be helpful https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/core-data-and-enterprise-iphone-applications-protecting-your-data/

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help this

[password encryption in iphone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189925/password-encryption-in-iphone-apps)

[iPhone encrypted and password protected?](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/iphone-faq/iphone-filevault-password-protection-microsoft-word-excel-powerpoint-pdf-outlook-support.html)